# Connecting Debian client to a Windows 10 Server via SMB

Tags: debian, samba, network-share, windows-10

I have my LAN setted up with SMB protocol and I can pretty much access all the shares from different OS Devices (Windows 10, DD-WRT NAS, Android), but I've got a problem when connecting the Debian Linux to the Windows 10 Shares.

The debian Linux is able to connect to the rest of the shares but Windows 10 ones is unable.
I'm running
`smbclient -L //WINDOWSPC -U WindowsUser`
which I get
`do_connect: Connection to WINDOWSPC failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)`

I've heard it may be that Windows10 Only accept smb 3.0 and does not easily communicate with non domain machines.

Comment: Windows 10 accepts smb 2 as well; smb 1 is not enabled by default. I suggest you to use `mount` as an alternative to `smbclient` or to just make a try. `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER,domain=DOMAIN_OR_WINDOWSPC,password=PASSWORD,uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) //WINDOWSPC/SHARE /mnt/`

Comment: on there I should change USER , DOMAIN_OR_WINDOWS , PASSWORD (I know those 3) , and anything else? also $UID? Where do I check that parameter? thx

Comment: Those 3, also SHARE, you should enter a share name on your WINDOWSPC. You can use /mnt to mount, or somewhere else on Debian. uid & gid parametres are set to your current user, no need to change them. I've added them so that your current user has read write access, although root (through sudo) mounts.